# How can I parse out the "somebody wrote..." part of an email text?

Tags: javascript, regex, email, github, filter

If you get a private message from Github, you can reply to it directly via email instead of going directly to the site to reply.

When Github receives your email, it parses the message and inserts it into the database.  I'm trying to do the same thing.

However, when my server receives the email as a raw string form, it gets something like this:

```
Important message here

On April 4, 2012 Somebody wrote:
    > blahblahblah
      On March 2, 2012 Somebody wrote:
           > blahblahbla
```

Of course, I only want the important message.  I don't want the rest of the junk that people wrote previously.

Is there a **universal** way to filter this out?  Some sort of library?

Or...do I have to examine Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail to determine what junk they add to the bottom of the message and then filter it out individually?

How does Github do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub uses their [email_reply_parser](https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser) gem for this.

> This is what GitHub uses to display comments that were created from email replies. This code is being open sourced in an effort to crowdsource the quality of our email representation.

Comment: This is like finding gold on the street.